# get values from two tables insert into single table using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

to get the values from two tables using unique ID and insert into another single table, this is my code, example: "table1" values and "table2" values copy and insert into "table3", finally delete the original values from old table.

```
 <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
include 'connection/db_connection.php';
$memberid=$_POST['memberid'];
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO existing_member (member_id,member_name,dob,gender,address,city,state,phone,email,height,weight,bmi,bp,medical,image_path,joining_date)
 SELECT member_id,member_name,dob,gender,address,city,state,phone,email,height,weight,bmi,bp,medical,image_path,joining_date FROM member_registration
 WHERE member_id='".$memberid."'" ); 

 /*
$query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO existing_member (membership_type) SELECT membership_type  FROM membership_details
WHERE member_id='".$memberid."'"); */

 $query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO existing_member (membership_type)
 SELECT a.membership_type as membership_type FROM membership_details a
INNER JOIN member_registration c ON c.member_id = a.member_id, c.member_name=a.member_name
where a.member_id='".$memberid."'");

if($query2)
{ 
    //$sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM member_registration WHERE member_id='".$memberid."'");
    //$sql1=mysql_query("delete from membership_details where member_id='".$memberid."'");

    echo "<script>
                alert('Data Deleted Successfully');
                window.location.href='close_member.php';
                </script>"; 
} 
else
{
echo "User Data Already Exist";
}
```

Comment: Seems you forgot the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your first query: `INSERT INTO existing_membe` forgot an `r` at the end of it.

Also a missing `y` at here: `if($quer and $query2)`

**NOTE**

- Do not use `mysql` functions, they are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.
- To avoid sql injection attacks, escape your variables what comes from users through `GET` or `POST` or use prepared statements.

Comment: now i corrected the errors, how to write code for two table values are copy to insert another single table,